# bash - output each array element on new line

Tags: arrays, bash, export

I am trying to create a TSV file from an array that I build inside a loop. I do get the values on each line to be tab separated, but I am not able to export each element of the array on a new line. This is an example:

```
OUTPUT=()
#header
OUTPUT+=$(printf "col_1\tcol_2\tcol_3")

param_1="bla"
param_2="tra"
param_3="meh"

for i in 1 .. 3
  do
    OUTPUT+=$(printf "$param_1\t$param_2\t$param_3")
done
#export
printf '%s\n' "${OUTPUT[@]}" > test.tsv
```

I have also tried to put `\n` at the end of each string that I insert in the array, but it did not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: if it's going to end up in a file, there is no need to have the intermediate array layer, you can directly write the elements to the file.  If you don't want the in-the-flight file to be visible, you can use a temp file and move to final name at the end.

Comment: yes, if you intend to use scripting in the future, this is *not* the way to be writing to files (although, yes, you can). Better to spend your time learning a tool designed for manipulating data (and reading/writing to files). Check out [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html) or if you need unlimited control and system features, OO, etc etc, find a python or perl tutorial that works for you. Good luck.

Comment: @karakfa I would avoid using a temp file and write at every iteration in it... why bother.. even if it is buffered and my output will not exceed half an MB. I can very well output only once at the end, no?

Comment: @shellter thanks for your comment. For this simple example I have no need to use `awk` or other dedicated tools. If I need to get something more complex done, then of course I would use something more appropriate. I just needed to write a script to be in line with the other existing scripts and not use a different programming language/tool just for a simple task

Comment: the reason is not exposing in-the-flight file to other processes prematurely. It's an integrity issue rather then performance.  However, may not be necessary in your particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To append to an array you should use this syntax:

```
array+=(content)
```

Also there is no need to use `printf` for appending the static text.

Here is a working script:

```
OUTPUT=()
#header
OUTPUT+=("col_1\tcol_2\tcol_3")

param_1="bla"
param_2="tra"
param_3="meh"

for i in {1..3}
do
    OUTPUT+=("$param_1\t$param_2\t$param_3")
done
#export
printf '%b\n' "${OUTPUT[@]}" > test.tsv
```

Note use of `%b` in `printf` so that escape sequences are interpreted correctly.

**Output:**

```
cat test.tsv

col_1   col_2   col_3
bla     tra     meh
bla     tra     meh
bla     tra     meh
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. It works now. So, the thing that actually makes a difference is the conversion to binary, `%b` in the `printf` exporting to file which will expand all escape characters. I have tried before without using `printf` while adding elements to the array but it would print all the string with `\t`. Thanks once again